# Freemarker: How to check for ?api-able type (v 2.3.26)

Tags: hashmap, freemarker

In Freemarker, I have a `Map<Map<...>>` in the model.

Due to FM glitch, querying for 2nd level `Map` needs `?api`. However, that escapes the normal value existence checks and complicates things.

This is what I have:

```
<#if sortedStatsMap[rowTag.name]?? && sortedStatsMap[rowTag.name]?is_hash>
    ${mapToJson(sortedStatsMap[rowTag.name]?api.get(boxTag.name))!}
</#if>
```

This ends up with:

```
APINotSupportedTemplateException: The value doesn't support ?api. See requirements in the FreeMarker Manual.
(FTL type: sequence+extended_hash+string (wrapper: f.c.DefaultToExpression$EmptyStringAndSequence),
TemplateModel class: f.c.DefaultToExpression$EmptyStringAndSequence, 
ObjectWapper: freemarker.template.DefaultObjectWrapper@1074040321(2.3.26, useAdaptersForContainers=true, forceLegacyNonListCollections=true, iterableSupport=trueexposureLevel=1, exposeFields=false, treatDefaultMethodsAsBeanMembers=true, sharedClassIntrospCache=@1896185155, ...))
The blamed expression:
==> sortedStatsMap[rowTag.name]!  [in template "reports/templates/techReport-boxes.ftl" at line 152, column 84]
```

If I try

```
sortedStatsMap[rowTag.name]!?is_hash
```

then this also fails because if missing, it gives me `empty_string_and_sequence` and `?is_hash` can't be applied, reportedly. (Says that in an error.)

What's the proper logic to check whether I can use `?api.get(key)`? Or the right way to use `!` to handle missing values or a missing key?

Comment: `?is_hash` should work with `EmptyStringAndSequence`, or with anything non-`null` for that mater. But I have also tried it, and it works for me. Can you check that again?

Comment: Is `boxTag.name` not always a non-`null` `String`? If it it is, what FM glitch do you ran into, which forces you to use `?api`?

Comment: It's true that the result of `thisIsNull!` doesn't support `?api`. But I don't see how your code can run into that, as where you use `?api`, you don't use `!`. Are you sure the example is accurate? (I also don't see why `?is_hash` is relevant. Note that supporting `?api` has nothing to do with being a hash.)

Comment: Ad 2) I thought FM is not capable of querying a map in a map. Hence `map[...]?api.get(key)`.  And the issue is that while that works if the "row" is present (that is, the result of `[...]`), it does not if it is not - then the result is `null`, which results in `empty_string_and_sequence`, to which `?api` is not applicable.

Comment: The goal is to have the simplest code to give me either the value at `map[row][col]`, or "" if either value is missing, never an error.

Comment: [Let's try](http://try.freemarker.org/) with `someMap = { "a": {"1": "A1" } }`

Comment: Oops: Can't use ?api, because the "api_builtin_enabled" configuration setting is false.   Anyway, `[][]` works there. Not sure if it was ever an issue. I'll try when I get back to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a value supports `?api` with `?has_api`. Though maybe you don't need that; the example and the problems related to it should be clarified (see my comments).